# How do I create a Webform that will open a case and assign case role

Tags: civicase, webform-civicrm

I'm trying to set up a webform to open a case and assign a case role.

3 contacts:
Source, 
Client, 
Case Coordinator

The open case part works great, but if I add the Case Coordinator relationship, it creates the relationship outside of the case.

If I add another activity (the first one is open case) and use assign case role, I don't get the option to choose which contact to use.

Any guidance?

Comment: Can you specify which version of CIviCRM and Webform-CiviCRM you are using?

Comment: CiviCRM 4.5.6 Webform-Civi integration 7.x-4.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I setup three contacts, all with just first and last name for simplicity sake.  Here is a screen shot of the case setup for Webform-CiviCRM 7x.4.10.

[image: Webform-CiviCRM Case Setup]

I haven't setup an activity to also be created when the form is submitted.

When the form is submitted, it creates the client, source contact and case coordinator.  Then creates the case with the client as the client and the case coordinator as the case manager

[image: Case Roles fieldset]

Note that it does also create the relationship between the client and the coordinator outside the case in addition to inside the case.  The rationale here is that if the client has more than one case, it would be useful to know who the other case coordinators for that client are.  This relationship will be automatically pulled into the Other Roles fieldset of subsequent case(s).

[image: Client Relationships Tab]

Joseph

Answer (score 0):

That is weird, we are doing this pretty often in our project. But I am not working on the Webforms, let me do a quick check on one. In one of our webforms I see a Case Manager field? (see attached print)[image]

Comment: When I do that, it attaches the "Case Manager" field to the activity, not the case.

Comment: Okay, I will refer the question to one of my webform wizard co-workers :-)